# How to see clob as formatted XML in TOAD popup editor

Tags: xml, editor, toad, clob

I use TOAD 10.6.1.3 and have stored some XML data as CLOB. This XML data doesn't have spaces, newlines etc. It is just straight string with some tags. When I clicked this CLOB area in a table, TOAD shows a popup editor with a single line of a XML. I want to see pretty-XML. Is there any way to do it? Because everytime i need to copy this CLOB into notepad++ and use formatter of notepad++...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Toad. Toad dropped support for XML in Toad 10.0 because Unicode support was added. OCI has several bugs with XMLTYPE when the Unicode flag is enabled that prevents Toad from working with it. The workaround is to use CLOB as you're doing or cast XMLTYPE to CLOB when querying. Because of the many problems all traces of XML support (formatting, XML tab in Editor, etc.) have been removed. However, you can format your XML using XMLSERIALIZE. The following script demonstrates this.

```
CREATE TABLE xml_format_test (fld CLOB);

INSERT INTO xml_format_test
        VALUES (
                  '<CATALOG><CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY><PRICE>10.90</PRICE><YEAR>1985</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1988</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE><ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1982</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE><ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY><PRICE>10.20</PRICE><YEAR>1990</YEAR></CD></CATALOG>');

COMMIT;

SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (DOCUMENT xmltype(fld)
                        VERSION '1.5'
                        INDENT SIZE=2) FROM xml_format_test;
```

Comment: It is not about my query. I select DATA tab of a TABLE from Describe Objects. There is a column with CLOB data type and It includes single line xml. My problem is seeing this clob column as a single line. When I click one of rows of this TABLE and double click on that column(CLOB) of this row, TOAD opens a popup called Grid Popup Editor and in this editor the date is a single line with xml

Comment: I know what you mean, I'm intimately familiar with Toad. To see your formatted XML though you'll need to write a query and use XMLSERIALIZE. There is no other way. If you want to view the data in the Schema Browser or Describe window then create a view. CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW XML_CLOB_VIEW AS SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (DOCUMENT xmltype(fld) VERSION '1.5' INDENT SIZE=2) fld_formatted FROM xml_clob x;

Comment: I thought you misunderstood me, so thank you for information. However, it is harder to do what you are offering me rather than just passing from one to another by a double click. So, there is another solution: putting this xml with new line and space characters. Yes, I know it will bring some cost...

Comment: The view solution would work well too with minimal impact. If you are just viewing the data and don't need to update it then you can create a view that clones the table except that the XML data is formatted. Then just describe the view instead of the table and your workflow remains the same as when using the table except you now see formatted XML in the popup window.